# Flex Instance Core Hours Sao Paulo

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

On our development environment, we have been charged about USD100 every month for an instance we didn't know existed (and of course we are not using), and we cant find in the entire AppEngine or Console Engine.

Also, the usage report shows no activity for the whole month, but we are still getting the charges.

The instance is: Flex Instance Core Hours Sao Paulo

I found similar posts in stackoverflow, so, here are the questions:
- is this some bad strategy from Google??? 
- where can I see this instance to stop it or delete it?
- where can I see who started this instance and when?

Of course, I called google support and no answer received.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Platform Support here! I found your ticket and see that you were provided an answer there already. In addition to what Dan described in his answer, if your app has currently the "Serving" status it will still run with the corresponding instances regardless of any requests incoming or not. As long as the version is serving it will continue to bill for hours that you are using. Also, if you are using automatic scaling with a minimum number of instances:

> that specified number of instances **run as resident instances** while any
>   additional instances are dynamic

(Instance scaling description in [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling))

You can use basic or manual scaling if this is not what you're interested in.

Comment: Hi Ania, thanks for your comment. I tried to clarify I did get a response from Google Support in one of my comments. 
I ended this by closing the project as it was a test project and we didn't know exactly when we created this instance (apparently when testing some firebase functionality) and also didn't find the way to stop the instance.
Thanks for your help and google support help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [App Engine Versions](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) pages for all your projects, you *should* find at least one with Flexible environment. The `Deployed` column should indicate who deployed it and when.

Based on that information you can decide to keep or delete the respective version(s). Simply stopping the instance may not be sufficient, depending on the scaling configuration for that service version GAE may automatically start one or more new instances.

You should also check the [App Engine Instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances) pages for your projects and cross-reference that with the versions info to make sure no undesired instances are accidentally left behind (at least in the standard environment they are normally stopped when the respective versions are deleted, not entirely certain the same is true for the flex environment)

The running flexible environment instances are billed by the hour, even if they receive no requests, which could explain why you're seeing charges without any activity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dan,
The App Engine Version shows all versions, but the flexible version are stopped for more than one month.
The App Engine Instance pages, for the last 30 days shows almost no activity.

From your last paragraph, I assume this flexible are charge also if there isn't any Active version, is that right?

Comment: If the instances are running yes.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the source of this instance was a firebase setting we made to make some test, and it automatically creates this instance. I shut off the billing account for this space, and instantly I received an email from firebase saying it detected changes that make some functions unavailable.